Not a valid choice for Flask WTForms SelectField
enter image description here
This is my Form Class:
class ProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    login = StringField("Login", validators=[DataRequired()])
    bday = DateField("Birthday", format="%Y-%m-%d")
    email = EmailField("Email")
    phone_number = StringField(
        "Phone Number",
    )
    sex = SelectField(
        coerce=str, choices=[("male", "Male"), ("female", "Female")], label="Sex"
    )
    preferences = StringField(
        "Preferences",
    )
    submit_changes = SubmitField("Submit Changes")
    adjust_data = SubmitField("Adjust User Data")

------------
This is my flask func for this page:
@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def profile():
    form = ProfileForm()
    adjust_mode = False
    db_sess = db_session.create_session()

    user = db_sess.query(User).filter_by(login=current_user.login).first()
    form.login.data = user.login

    if user.users_data:
        user_data = user.users_data[0]
        form.bday.data = user_data.bday
        form.email.data = user_data.email
        form.phone_number.data = user_data.phone_number
        form.sex.data = user_data.sex
    else:
        user_data = UserData(user=user)
        db_sess.add(user_data)
        db_sess.commit()

    form.login.render_kw = {"disabled": True}
    form.bday.render_kw = {"disabled": True}
    form.email.render_kw = {"disabled": True}
    form.phone_number.render_kw = {"disabled": True}
    form.sex.render_kw = {"disabled": True}
    form.preferences.render_kw = {"disabled": True}

    if form.adjust_data.data:
        adjust_mode = True
        form.login.render_kw = {"disabled": False}
        form.bday.render_kw = {"disabled": False}
        form.email.render_kw = {"disabled": False}
        form.phone_number.render_kw = {"disabled": False}
        form.sex.render_kw = {"disabled": False}
        form.preferences.render_kw = {"disabled": False}

    elif form.submit_changes.data and form.validate_on_submit():
        user_data.bday = form.bday.data
        user_data.zodiac_sign = get_zodiac_sign(form.bday.data)
        user_data.email = form.email.data
        user_data.phone_number = form.phone_number.data
        user_data.sex = form.sex.data

        if form.login.data != user.login:
            user.login = form.login.data

        db_sess.commit()
        return redirect("/")

    return render_template("profile.html", form=form, adjust_mode=adjust_mode)

I'm except the field to work correctly.
I've tried to add
validate_choice=False

param to my field but the validation doesn't work correctly.
All Fields data became None.
Field data should be STR so coerce param must be str.
